Flutter web: Find text on page is not highlighting text if it contains whitespaces
In Flutter web page, flutter has custom handler to find/search elements on page. But it fails to highlight if search text has any whitespaces.
If you see in attached screenshot, it is able to find bank accoun by seeing count (1/1) but it is not highlighting full bank accoun text on web page. It highlights till single continuous word bank and stops highlighting afterwords.



As far as I know, you cannot search text in flutter web page as flutter draws on a canvas, can you explain how you have implemented the custom handler you were talking about.

Please always post relevant code to your question: minimal reproducible example

@AkhilSuthapalli I think this is out-of-box behaviour

@PeterPointer there is no separate code implementation. The current app in flutter may have same behaviour.

Well if that is the case it's time to open a ticket for flutter if you believe it should behave differently. This community is about fixing code you wrote yourself.

I want to know if there exists a solution which I couldn't find online, Flutter might already be knowing as this is common bug and community can help.
